# gantt package progress bar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I would like to know if it is possible to provide the progression for each taskbar by partially filling with a completion percentage.

The picture below clarifies the idea that I had in mind. All help is highly appreciated.

Greetings.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\gantt}{-0.5}{-1.5}{}{}

\newcommand{\defcolor}{blue}

\begin{document}

    \begin{gantt}[drawledgerline=true]{18}{24}
        % vertical, horizontal 'boxes'
    \begin{ganttitle}  % First title: Year 
        \numtitle{2019}{1}{2019}{24}  
        % start, label, width 
    \end{ganttitle}

    \begin{ganttitle} % Second title: Months
        \titleelement{Feb}{4}
        \titleelement{Mar}{4}
        \titleelement{Apr}{4}
        \titleelement{May}{4}
        \titleelement{Jun}{4}
        \titleelement{Jul}{4}
    \end{ganttitle}

    \begin{ganttitle} % Third title: Weeks
        \numtitle{6}{1}{29}{1}
        % start, skip, end, width       
    \end{ganttitle}

    %---------------------------------------
     \ganttmilestone{Task A}{0} % Milestone: Label, position
    %---------------------------------------


    %--------------------------------------- 
    %   Task B
    %---------------------------------------
    \ganttgroup{Task B}{0}{6} % start, width 
    %
    \ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{0}{1}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{1}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{1}{4}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task B}{3}{3}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task B}{6}
    %---------------------------------------


    %--------------------------------------- 
    %   Task C
    %---------------------------------------
    \ganttgroup{Task C}{6}{15} % start, width 
    %
    \ganttbar[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{6}{2}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{8}{8}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{15}{3}
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{16}{4}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{20}
    %
    \ganttbarcon[color=\defcolor]{Task C}{20}{1}
    %
    \ganttmilestonecon{Task C}{21}
    %---------------------------------------
    \end{gantt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is an "official" package called [`pgfgantt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en) that allows you to draw such things. How about switching to this package?

Comment: If it were to maintain a similar lay-out/design for the bars that would've been an option. I tried to do it in pgfgantt myself, but I was not able to reproduce a similar design as produced by the gantt package.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there is a usually a threshold to base answers on "inofficial" packages. This is not necessarily because they are often not of the same quality as the "official" ones, but because it is then not clear who, apart from the OP, will benefit from an answer. The "inofficial" package may be gone in 5 minutes.

Comment: I get the point you're making. However, the package will not be gone in 5 minutes though. Could you perhaps show how you would approach this problem in the pgfgantt package while maintaining the same design/lay-out as used in the package gantt?

Comment: I am not very experienced with this package. The above was more a comment with the aim of explaining why your in principle very interesting question did not receive the attention you may have hoped for. I guess it would be best if you could try to translate your code to the syntax of the official package.